# Access Top Row In Gridview from DataTable When Button Clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview thats its filtered. My question is how do I access the top row of that filtered Gridview thru the DataTable after it has been filtered when Button is Clicked

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Id, Num, Trans, S ,Est_Trans,Linked FROM vwOpenTcktSum_TransTypeTotal WHERE (Q = @Q)  AND (S = @S)", cs);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Q", Q);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S", S);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt = ds.Tables[0];

DataTable newDataTable = dt.AsEnumerable()
         .Where(r => !ListLinkedIds.Contains(r.Field<int>("LinkedTicketId")))
          .CopyToDataTable();

 Session["Data"] = ds;
 gvMain.DataSource = newDataTable; //Datasource
 gvMain.DataBind();


 protected void btnGetNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      //Get Top Row from Gridview
 }
```

Comment: What are you using to filter your GridView?

Comment: @GarrisonNeely DataTable newDataTable = dt.AsEnumerable()
         .Where(r => !ListLinkedIds.Contains(r.Field<int>("LinkedTicketId")))
          .CopyToDataTable();

Comment: Is already filtered the final DataTable is newDataTable

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306990/getting-a-datarow-from-an-asp-net-gridview

Comment: @GarrisonNeely what I want to do is how do I access the data for that Top Row, I want to know the values inside of each column and  index[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After RowIndex in a grid view, you can go to Cell[index] for each column.

```
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can't access the datasource after binding...

Unfortunately, you won't be able to access the datatable itself on button-click because the datasource is disposed after being bound to the gridview control. The only times at which you can pull data from the datatable is when it is initially created or when it is bound to a gridview row. To access the row-data-binding part of the life-cycle, I think the gridview attribute is called OnRowDataBound, but I normally use repeater controls so I can't really say from experience.

---

### Access the data row instead...

Having said that, you can however access the data from the row itself. This can be done by using the parent (or ancestor) of the sender (assuming the sender is a button in the gridview row). Cast the sender's parent as the gridview and then look in its rows collection for the row you need, in this case the index would probably be 0 for the first row.

---

### Bonus info:

I was going to type up an example for you, but the link provided in N4TKD's comment explains it well. Here it is again if you missed it:

- [Getting a DataRow from an ASP.NET GridView - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306990/getting-a-datarow-from-an-asp-net-gridview)

Comment: thats what I need How can I access the DataRow with index[0], I want to retrieve the data for each column for that top row.

Comment: @Apollo Check out the way he did it in the first answer on that link I posted. I have used it a few times but I would have to look at the code again and it wouldn't be in C# anyway.