# Get original object from DataRow in GridView C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I try to display a collection (`IEnumerable`) of objects (generated via Linq to Sql). Therefore I bind the `Gridview`s `DataSource` property to the generated output of my Linq to SQL method. In the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `GridView` I try to convert the selected rows `DataItem` back to my original object but end up with a `null` value instead.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RlDataContext dc = new RlDataContext();
    this.dgvReports.DataSource = dc.GetReports(1);
    this.dgvReports.DataBind();
}

protected void dgvReports_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dgvReports.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        Report rpt = (Report)this.dgvReports.SelectedRow.DataItem;
    }
}
```

The return type of GetReports is `ISingleResult<Report>`

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly, the `DataItem` of repeaters is no longer available after the Page_Load.  Therefore as part of the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, `DataItem` will be null.  Not sure if there is anything you can do about that (which is why this is a comment rather than an answer).  One option is to build data to be held locally during the initial `DataBind` and use that in the event handler

Comment: Please Refer This [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306990/getting-a-datarow-from-an-asp-net-gridview) Might Help u..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a bindingsource between your datagridview and your list. When a selection is made is datagridview use the bindingsource's `Current` property to get you the right item from the list.

Comment: BindingSource seems to be part of the 'WinForms' namespace. Should I import this namespace just for the use of BindingSource. Isn't there a way to exploit the ASP.Net functionality?

Comment: This link might be helpful for you. http://forums.asp.net/t/1645349.aspx?BindingSource+Equivalent+in+ASP+Net+web+programming+

Comment: The only way I found was to create your own collection during the DataBaound event. Since this is not feasible for me I'll stick with the BindingSource solution. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I always get my information from a datagridview

```
    string variabel = yourDataGridView["Columnname"].ToString();
```

You can also use this in a loop then it will be:

```
    string variabel = yourDataGridView["RowNumber"].Cells["Columnname"].Value.ToString();
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But this dosn't help ma as it only gets a column tex. What I want is the original object that was bound to the gridView.

Comment: Customer cust = row.DataBoundItem as Customer;
if (cust != null)
{
    cust.SendInvoice();
}

Perhaps this helps then.

Comment: GridViewRow has no property 'DataBoundItem'. Are you sure you're targeting the ASP.Net gridView and not hte WinForms DataGridView?

Comment: I used to work with WinForms. Don't know if there is a difference between ASP.Net GridView and WinForms Gridview